# Should I wrap getSharedPreferences inside try catch?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I use this function to extract shared preferences from Android App. However, I am not sure if the requested field exists. Should I wrap the code inside try catch or `getString()` is safe when the field does not exist?

```
public String loadPreferences(String what){
    SharedPreferences settings  =this.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String content =settings.getString(what, "empty");
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [read documentation of getString here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), it clearly says,

> Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws
>   ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
>   a String. This value may be null.

In your case, **defValue** is **"empty"**

So exception is possible only when value you are trying to return is not of specified type, it should never be the case of `getString()` though

Answer (score 2):

If by "field", you mean the value keyed by whatever `what` is, `getString()` will not return `null` in your code snippet. It will return the value keyed by whatever `what` is, or `"empty"` if there is no value for that preference.

Comment: is "Having no value" equal to "Not existing"?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you search through this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

You will find this method :

```
getString(String key, String defValue)
```

Which means if you havnt stored anything in SharedPreferences with this key and you are trying to get value for this key than it will return default value

So in your case

```
String content =settings.getString(what, "empty");
```

For `what` key if you havnt stored anything with this key and if you are trying to get its value than it will return default value that is `"empty"` in your case